# How do I fix the unity warning: You are trying to create a MonoBehavior using the 'new' keyword?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I fix the unity warning: You are trying to create a MonoBehavior using the 'new' keyword?

```
public class CardDatabase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static List<Card> cardList = new List<Card>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        cardList.Add(new Card(0, "Blank", 1, 1, 1, "111b"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the full warning that includes what you should do instead?

Comment: [That is by design](https://answers.unity.com/questions/653904/you-are-trying-to-create-a-monobehaviour-using-the-2.html)

Answer (score 2):

The warning pretty much explains itself. Your card class is ***MonoBehavior*** and you should not use the 'new' keyword to create it. You have two options: First option is to remove the MonoBehavior from your class, something like this:

```
public class CardDatabase: MonoBehaviour
{

    public class Card
    {
        public Card(int intVal1, string strVal1, int intVal2, int intVal3, int intVal4, string strVal2)
        {
            this.intVal1 = intVal1;
            this.strVal1 = strVal1;
            this.intVal2 = intVal2;
            this.intVal3 = intVal3;
            this.intVal4 = intVal4;
            this.strVal2 = strVal2;
        }
        public int intVal1;
        public string strVal1;
        public int intVal2;
        public int intVal3;
        public int intVal4;
        public string strVal2;
    }

    public static List<Card> cardList = new List<Card>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        cardList.Add(new Card(0, "Blank", 1, 1, 1, "111b"));
    }
}
```

Second option is to keep the MonoBehavior on Card class and use instantiate or add component to create new cards. For example this is your card script:

```
public class Card : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int intVal1;
    public string strVal1;
    public int intVal2;
    public int intVal3;
    public int intVal4;
    public string strVal2;
}
```

And this is your other script:

```
public class CardDatabase: MonoBehaviour
{

    public static List<Card> cardList = new List<Card>();
    public Card cardPrefab = null; // Assign in the inspector

    private void Awake()
    {
        Card card = new GameObject("Card").AddComponent<Card>();
        card.intVal1 = 0;
        card.strVal1 = "Blank";
        card.intVal2 = 1;
        card.intVal3 = 1;
        card.intVal4 = 1;
        card.strVal2 = "111b";
        cardList.Add(card);

        // Or

        Card card2 = Instantiate(cardPrefab);
        card2.intVal1 = 0;
        card2.strVal1 = "Blank";
        card2.intVal2 = 1;
        card2.intVal3 = 1;
        card2.intVal4 = 1;
        card2.strVal2 = "111b";
        cardList.Add(card2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The third option: Using [ScriptableObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html).